# Turbo linker error 2003 on dosbox

Tags: assembly, tasm, dosbox

I try to run Turbo Linker (tlink) on dosbox and for some reason it fails.

I'm using Windows7 64bit therefore I can't ran turbo asm and turbo linker.

Well, I was running `tlink/t hw1` at the dosbox and I got this message:

```
C:\tlink/t hw1
Stub error (2003): can't find dpmi16bi.ovl
```

Do you know how to solve this error ? And why does it happen?

Answer (score 1):

You don't have the rest of the product (Turbo C, Turbo Pascal, Turbo C++, Borland C, etc) installed. `dmpi16bi.ovl` was an overlay library (sort of an old DOS type of swapfile use thing that shifted stuff into extended or expanded memory, to allow more than 640KB of RAM to be used). Without it, you're missing a big part of `TLink` itself.

Comment: thanks but when I ran it on Windows XP 32bit there were no problems.. so what is the cause for the missing file?

Comment: It's not installed properly for `tlink` to find while running under DOSBox, obviously. If it runs on XP, but not DOSBox, it's a problem with the way it was installed for DOSBox.

Comment: @iLoveC: Add the TLINK directory where the `DPMI16BI.OVL` is found to the `PATH` environment variable of DOSBox.

Comment: @Jay: There are going to need to be some other environmental variables set, IIRC, which is why I suggested doing a proper installation under DOSBox.

Comment: @iLoveC Windows provides a built-in DPMI server for DOS apps, but under pure DOS you need an external one.

Answer (score 1):

There's a simple solution. You could just use TLINK.EXE from the Turbo C++ 1.01 package (available for free online), which does not use any overlay modules, nor it uses DPMI.